# jQuery in Codeception is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, selenium, codeception

I'm using Codeception to write acceptance tests for an app that relies on jQuery. I got the WebDriver to open FireFox and login. JavaScript is enabled, and I can do `$I->executeJS('return document.getElementById("some-element")');` which returns the element. For the life of me, I can't access jQuery at all. I know it's loaded because the jQuery plugins on the page are working. I need to interact with then.

So far, I've tried two approaches. The first is that I create a hidden div with an ID when the DOM is ready. Then in my test, I do this:

```
public function foo(AcceptanceTester $I) {
    $I->waitForElement('#dom-ready');
    $var = $I->executeJS('return jQuery.fn.jquery');
    var_dump($var);
}
```

That var_dump should return the jQuery version. It's returns null.

I've also tried this:

```
public function foo(AcceptanceTester $I) {
    $I->wait(20); // Some really high number of seconds
    $var = $I->executeJS("return window.jQuery != undefined && jQuery.active == 0");
    var_dump($var);
}
```

That var_dump should be true. It's always false. I'm totally at a loss. What am I no seeing here?

Here is my `acceptance.suite.yaml` file

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: 'http://site.local/' # put your local url
            browser: firefox
            capabilities:
                javascriptEnabled: true
                handlesAlerts: true
                webStorageEnabled: true
        - \Helper\Acceptance
```

Comment: Have you tried with the `$` shorthand ? `return !window.$ || window.$.active == 0`

Comment: Yup, doesn't work either. Besides, if jQuery isn't defined, the shorthand certainly won't be.

Comment: I had some cases where `JQuery` was self contained in the `$` namespace. It could also be due to an issue from the geckodriver. Try this `var w = window.wrappedJSObject || window; return !w.$ || w.$.active < 1;`

Comment: That returns false for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! The issue was indeed with Firefox, not Selenium. Thanks Florent B for suggesting the idea that the geckodriver could be the issue. Short answer is you need at least FF >= 48 to access jQuery.

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/108

Hope this helps someone. Took me almost a week to resolve this.